# SELECT all rows for a given month and output the rows split by weeks of the month

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table Trip which has fields:

```
id int

Weekdate DATE  (date field shows Monday's date)

Trip VARCHAR

Driver VARCHAR

TripPrice DOUBLE
```

...

I use select to pick a month to select all rows from the table for the month and need to output data split by weeks of the month. It should look like:

```
July:
-----------------------
WEEK1: 2013-05-01 ...

WEEK1: 2013-05-01 ...

WEEK1: 2013-05-01 ...

WEEK1_TOTAL: sum(tripprice)
-----------------------
WEEK2: 2013-05-08 ...

WEEK2: 2013-05-08 ...

WEEK2: 2013-05-08 ...

WEEK2_TOTAL: sum(tripprice)

-----------------------
```

Any ideas?

Comment: several ideas, how about you?

Comment: Please post your code of what you have tried.

Comment: one idea http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: What do you mean "week of the month?" Do your weeks always begin on the first / eighth / fifteenth / twenty-second / twenty-eighth days of each month? or are they the calendar weeks that are partially or wholly in the month in question.